# Why are the constructor Zlib_init kept private in class Zlib_init in the book by Bjarne Stroustrup

Tags: c++, private-constructor

In the book The C++ Programming Language, by Bjarne Stroustrup, the author says:

> Sometimes when you design a library, it is necessary, or simply convenient, to invent a type with a constructor and a destructor with the sole purpose of initialization and cleanup. Such a type would be used once only: to allocate a static object so that the constructor and the destructor are called. For example:
>
> ```
>  class  Zlib_init
> {
>     Zlib_init() ; //get Zlib ready for use
>    ~Zlib_init()  ; //clean up after Zlib
> };
> Class Zlib
> {
>    static  Zlib_init   x;
>    /  /...
> };
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, it is not guaranteed that such an object is initialized before its first use and destroyed after its last use in a program consisting of separately compiled units.

Why does the author keep the constructor and destructor as private members? 
And why won't this method work if we use it in a program consisting of seperately compiled units? 
Won't it require definition of the member `x` for calling the constructor `Zlib_init()` and destructor `~Zlib_init()`? Then what is the use of this method?
It's in section 10.4.9 of the book.

Comment: that is not going to compile - for multiple reasons

Comment: that seems more illustrative than an actual demonstration of working code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Why does the author keep the constructor and destructor as private members?**

The constructor & destructor being `private` seems to be a typo.
Class `static` members needs to be **defined** in order that you can **use** them. In order that the static member `x` is defined the constructor needs to be accessible. if not the linker will complain about undefined reference.

**[Online Sample](http://ideone.com/95lMZ)**:

```
class  Zlib_init 
{    
   Zlib_init() ; //get Zlib ready for use  
  ~Zlib_init()  ; //clean up after Zlib 
   public:
     int j;
};
class Zlib 
{  
   public:  
   static  Zlib_init   x;    
}; 

Zlib_init Zlib::x;

int main()
{
    Zlib::x.j = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
prog.cpp:3: error: ‘Zlib_init::Zlib_init()’ is private     
prog.cpp:14: error: within this context      
prog.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Zlib::__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)’:     
prog.cpp:4: error: ‘Zlib_init::~Zlib_init()’ is private     
prog.cpp:14: error: within this context
```

> **And why won't this method work if we use it in a program consisting of seperately compiled units?**

If you fix the typo mentioned above by [making the constructor and destructor `public`](http://ideone.com/WxsBw) or by making [`Zlib` a friend of class `Zlib_init`](http://ideone.com/Dd6EW) the code still faces another problem.
The problem is popularly known as **Static Initialization Fiasco** in C++.

**Good Read:**

[[10.14] What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)
[[10.17] How do I prevent the "static initialization order fiasco" for my static data members?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use-members.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the additional information on static initialization fiasco..

Comment: Typos happen from time to time in B.Stroustrup's books and articles. I guess, this is the code that he writes by heart. Having no time to test.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the author keep the constructor and destructor as private members?

I'm only guessing, but I assume that the author stripped down the declaration to the bare minimum neccessary to convey his idea. Although a `struct` instead of a `class` would have worked just as well, and in other places of his book the author uses an ellipsis (…) in such cases. So I'm not sure.

> And why won't this method work if we use it in a program consisting of seperately compiled units?

The constructor of a static object will run before `main`, so if you only use `Zlib` in stuff called from `main`, everything works well. The problems start if some other static object in some other compilation unit attempts to use `Zlib` in its constructor. There are no guarantees about the order in which these two constructors get executed, so you might end up by some code trying to use an uninitialized `Zlib` class.